# Push to Heroku from different remote

Tags: heroku, github, bitbucket

Up until now I was using github and pushing to Heroku. I had something like this and when I did `git push heroku master` it pushed to Heroku from I presume origin remote.

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/gentle-dawn-61312.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/gentle-dawn-61312.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:Igor-Vuk/App.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Igor-Vuk/rApp.git (push)
```

Now I added bitbucket where I also deploy my code so now I have something like this.

```
bitbucket       ssh://git@bitbucket.org/Igor-Vuk/App.git (fetch)
bitbucket       ssh://git@bitbucket.org/Igor-Vuk/App.git (push)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/gentle-dawn-61312.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/gentle-dawn-61312.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:Igor-Vuk/App.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Igor-Vuk/App.git (push)
```

How would I push to heroku now code that is deployed to bitbucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same command. If you run `git push heroku master` on your system, then the push originates on your system and goes directly to Heroku without involving either Bitbucket or GitHub.

Comment: omg, you are right. I was under delusion that I should push to Github before deploying.

Comment: It's still a good idea to have the current commit on a remote repo other than Heroku, just in case. The command you were running won't do that on its own, though you could potentially have something like Bitbucket Pipelines handle the push to Heroku.